# How to completely fit an image in PDF using XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I am creating a PDF file using XSL-FO. I am trying to insert an image using below code:-

```
<fo:block-container margin-left="-1%" margin-right="-1%" margin-top="-0.5%" height="48.4%">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic src="D:\MainImage.jpg" width="100%" height="14cm" scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>
                        </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

The image is getting inserted but it is leaving a very small gap both on left and right side, which I don't want it to, it should completely cover left and right portion of my PDF file.

Any idea what changed to make?

Comment: I am able to achieve this by doing margin-left="-1%" margin-right="1%", is this a right approach or there is some standard way?

Comment: Is there any white-space at the edges of the actual image?  Does the containing `fo:block` (or anything that contains that) set a margin?

Comment: @TonyGraham, Hi, No there are no white-spaces at the edges of Image. I have kept it inside fo:block-container, where I have defined margin-left="-1%" margin-right="-1%" margin-top="-0.5%".

Comment: @TonyGraham, Hi , I have edited the question for clarity on code.

Comment: Why are you specifying scaling="non-uniform"? This distorts the image, and is usually not desirable.

Comment: What happens when you specify width="102%" on the external-graphic?

Comment: @Hobbes, Actually I want the image to occupy exactly half portion of my PDF page, when I make width="102%", scaling="uniform" and remove margin-left="-1%" margin-right="-1%" , it does not cover half portion of my page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work in % usually, because it presents a moving target. Your block-container margins depend on the width of the page, and your image width depends on something else.

1. Watch out for margins, border, padding and spacing set by surrounding blocks. Set them all to 0 to eliminate trouble there.
2. Set the width of the external-graphic to be equal to the width of the body region, not as a percentage but as a measurement.